# Installing twilio video app react with strong filter

Tags: filter, twilio

I'm sorry, I'm not an experimented programmer.

I'm trying to install twilio video app react
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react

I'm using a strong internet filter:
https://netfree.link/

I get the following error message (running on Windows 10):

[PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whw1g.png)

May it be the internet filter that block the installation ?

edit:
here is the log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy:twilio-cli'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'predeploy:twilio-cli',
4 verbose run-script   'deploy:twilio-cli',
4 verbose run-script   'postdeploy:twilio-cli'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~predeploy:twilio-cli: twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1
6 info lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1
7 verbose lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Yaacov\twilio-video-app-react\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Yaacov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Yaacov\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: CWD: C:\Users\Yaacov\twilio-video-app-react
10 silly lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env REACT_APP_SET_AUTH=passcode npm run build && twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication=passcode --app-directory ./build'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1~deploy:twilio-cli: Failed to exec deploy:twilio-cli script
13 verbose stack Error: twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1 deploy:twilio-cli: `cross-env REACT_APP_SET_AUTH=passcode npm run build && twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication=passcode --app-directory ./build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Yaacov\twilio-video-app-react
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy:twilio-cli"
18 verbose node v14.15.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1 deploy:twilio-cli: `cross-env REACT_APP_SET_AUTH=passcode npm run build && twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication=passcode --app-directory ./build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the twilio-video-app-react@0.2.1 deploy:twilio-cli script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: It would be better if you copy and paste the error message in your question.

Comment: Do you have the [Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart) installed?

Answer (score 1):

I checked with the help service of filter, they stopped to block the access for some link and now it works.